# Aligning column around decimal with footnotes present

Tags: footnotes, dcolumn

I have a column of numbers which I'd like to align on the decimal point, which in simpler circumstances I've achieved using the `dcolumn` package.

In this particular case, I have footnotes which are now distorting the layout, and I'd like to know how I can resolve this. A simplified version of my `tabular` environment is shown below, along with an image of the output with and without footnotes. Without the footnotes it displays fine, but with them the last number is shifted over.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
    1.234 \textsuperscript{b}       \\
    -0.001 \textsuperscript{b}      \\
    -12.345 \textsuperscript{b}     \\
    123 \textsuperscript{c}         \\
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue the "footnote" with a zero-width `r`ight over`lap`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1}}
    1.234 &   1.234 \textsuperscript{b} \\
   -0.001 &  -0.001 \textsuperscript{b} \\
  -12.345 & -12.345 \textsuperscript{b} \\
  123     & 123     \rlap{\textsuperscript{c}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A LaTeX approach would be `\makebox[0pt][l]` instead of using `\rlap`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have used `\rlap` and it works fine. I am not familiar with the \rlap code though, and can't seem to find any documentation on it. Could you suggest somewhere I can learn more about what it does?

Comment: @Ulysses: `\rlap` is defined as `\hbox to 0pt{#1 \hss}`. You can issue `\show\rlap` to see the definition in your `.log`, as an example. If you want to know about overlapping, consider reading the [`adjustbox` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf).

Comment: I know `\rlap{...}` is easier to write, but I always recommend using `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` (maybe hidden in a `\tnote` macro, following `threeparttable`). People not having deep knowledge of plain TeX might get very bad surprises from `\rlap` or `\llap`.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested to the `threeparttable` package that features a `\tnote` macro that just does what you want (and much more).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{A very interesting table}\label{tab-interest}

\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1} D{.}{.}{-1}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\
\midrule
Gnus           &   1.234 &   4.567 &   1.234\tnote{a} \\
Gnats          &  -0.001 &   0.12  &   3.51\tnote{b} \\
Gnats and gnus & -12.34  &  -42    & -42\tnote{c} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Fried
\item[b] Stuffed
\item[c] Boiled
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different way of doing the same thing, with some more facilities, is with `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{A very interesting table}\label{tab-interest1}

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=-2.3]
 S[table-format=-2.3]
 S[table-format=-2.3]
}
\toprule
& {A} & {B} & {C} \\
\midrule
Gnus           &   1.234 &   4.567 &   1.234\tnote{a} \\
Gnats          &  -0.001 &   0.12  &   3.51\tnote{b} \\
Gnats and gnus & -12.34  &  -42    & -42\tnote{c} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Fried
\item[b] Stuffed
\item[c] Boiled
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{A very interesting table}\label{tab-interest2}

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=-2.3]
 S[table-format=-2.3]
 S[table-format=-2.3,table-align-text-post = false]
}
\toprule
& {A} & {B} & {C} \\
\midrule
Gnus           &   1.234 &   4.567 &   1.234\tnote{a} \\
Gnats          &  -0.001 &   0.12  &   3.51\tnote{b} \\
Gnats and gnus & -12.34  &  -42    & -42\tnote{c} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Fried
\item[b] Stuffed
\item[c] Boiled
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]